# How to filtering tag using Django2.0 and django-taggit0.22.1

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I have a problem which I can't resolve. I tried to implement tags features in my blog project in Python/Django 2.0. I installed `django-taggit0.22.1.`

I have a class Post with atributte `tags = TaggableManager()`

I also have a few posts object with tags. 
For example in `python manage.py shell` I import my `Post models` and I do command:

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
```

I have a post named `Post: Django 2.0`

then I use

```
tag = post.tags.all()
```

"tag" variable shows me this

```
"QuerySet [<\Tag: django\>], <\Tag: programming\>, <\Tag: jazz\>"
```

Then I want to filter my tags.

I download all my published posts

```
published= Post.published.all()
```

and finally I want do filter posts by tags using this:

```
published.filter(tags__name__in=['music'])
```

I see this

> error: TypeError: get_path_info() takes 1 positional argument but 2
>   were given

What is the main problem ?

This filtering method I saw on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-taggit

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest release django-taggit 0.22.1 [adds testing for Django 1.11](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/294fe61b01ec8d6d24f1bfd30e4345d6ada33f6f/CHANGELOG.txt#L4). There is not yet a release that supports Django 2.0.

In the meantime, you could try running the branch in [pull request 509](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/294fe61b01ec8d6d24f1bfd30e4345d6ada33f6f/CHANGELOG.txt#L4https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/pull/509).

Comment: Using your suggestions I tried this branch. The same problem.

Comment: Do you get the same error with Django 1.11? It might be worth opening an issue on the repository. Include the *full* traceback and not just the last line.

Comment: In Django 1.11 there is no problem. I opened a new issue on the repository.